# What are the Rails object 'extend' supported paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extend

This has been frustrating me for 1/2 a day.

I'm trying to extend a Model of mine from a module .rb file located in a non-typical location. In my Model I try extending to a Module based on an Attribute in the Model. The Models are passed to a View, and I want the View to call the same Module method ("content") in all cases regardless of the Model's path Attribute.

```
 Test < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   after_initialization do |test|
     if !self.path.nil?
       if File.exists?('app/views/' + self.path + '/_extend.rb')
         extend 'app/views/' + self.path + '/_extend'
       end
     end
   end
   ...
 end
```

Just trying to dynamically add a class method from a different file. I want to try and keep things organized, which is why I want to stuff all my Module methods into the Model with a giant switch case.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: That's... confusing, at least to me. Also, why are you extend a model class with anything from the view layer? Are you sure this is an appropriate way to break up your functionality?

Comment: Ignore the path I didn't paint the whole picture here. I'm only trying to extend the Model via a Module that's stored in a separate file. It's stored in a separate file because I'd like to create a generator later that will neatly generate the _extend.rb and a couple of other Model type specific files. (_config.erb and _view.erb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ruby's `extend` method does not work with paths. You need to supply the module you want to extend. So you should not store a `path` but rather some kind of `type` that you can later use to get a reference to the module you want to extend. A little example:

```
module GuestBehavior
  def has_access?
    false
  end
end

module AdminBehavior
  def has_access?
    true
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :extend_behavior

  def extend_behavior
    return if kind.blank?
    behavior_module = "#{kind.capitalize}Behavior".constantize
    extend behavior_module
  end
end

admin = User.new(:kind => 'admin')
guest = User.new(:kind => 'guest')

admin.has_access? # => true
guest.has_access? # => false
```

This is more a though experiment than code I would actually write. It should give you an idea how to achieve your goal.

**EDIT:** If you want to put the modules in different places you can easily get it working. Assuming your using rails, there is the autoloader. When you access an undefined constant the autoloader kicks in and tries to load the file, which defines that constat. The above example could look something like:

```
app/models/guest_behavior.rb
app/models/admin_behavior.rb
```

You don't need to put any `require` statements in the code. Rails will automatically load the files when you access `GuestBehavior` or `AdminBehavior`. (thats what the `constantize` call does)

Comment: Thanks for the great response. This is basically what I'm trying to accomplish, but I wanted the 'behaviour_module' in your example to come from a separate module file. I wanted to avoid using 'load' or 'require', or write some magical bit to pull a loaded module methods into my Model so I could call the same method irrespective of the type. I think I'm going to resort to extending my Model from within its .rb. It's a shame because I wanted to write a generator to simplify creation of the Model, and some additional Model type specific files. (_config.erb and _view.erb)

Comment: If you have a suggestion on how to extend a Module into a class from a file, I'll take it. Globally loading the Model would be a pain because I would have to uniquely name each Module. (if they were extended from files only the path would need to be unique)

Comment: @garlicman Perhaps an initializer, then. Also, you ad whatever directories you want to the library autoload paths.

Comment: @DaveNewton I thought about that but I was trying to avoid getting specific about naming the Modules. If I use an initializer I would have to declare all the Modules separately/uniquely. I was hoping to leave identifying the Module to extend from by looking in that Model's path attribute for a stand named file.rb with a standard named Module. If you have a suggestion on how to do this in an initializer I'm definitely all ears and thumbs!

Comment: I decided to go with stuffing the Model's extend Modules in the Model .rb in the end. I can't auto generate new Modules into an existing Module, but this will and does work. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how you can put the modules in separate files.